# Encontrando pg_dump e pg_restore (PostgreSQL) em meu computador com C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

Para realizar o backup e restore em uma base de dados em PostgreSQL utilizando  C# é necessário localizar alguns arquivos como o `pg_dump` e `pg_restore`.

Como eu faço uma função para que seja possível encontrar os arquivos? ou seja uma especie de varredura no computador, para encontrar os arquivos do PostgreSQL

Comment: Esses arquivos possuem alguma extensão? Exemplo: ".exe", ".txt"

Comment: Sim, são ".exe"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei um método, que é possível encontrar o pg_dump ou outros programas, sem a necessidade da elevação de usuário

```
   private void VerificaPg() {
        CaminhoPg = BuscarArquivo_Dump("pg_dump.exe");
        if (CaminhoPg == String.Empty)
            MessageBox.Show("Postgres não está instalado");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(CaminhoPg);
    }


    private String BuscarArquivo_Dump(String Arquivo)
    {
        String RotaDump = String.Empty;
        try
        {
            DriveInfo[] Drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (DriveInfo Drive in Drives)
            {
                RotaDump = RealizarBusca(Drive.Name, Arquivo);
                if (RotaDump.Length != 0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        return RotaDump;
    }

    private String RealizarBusca(String DirName, String NomeArchivo)
    {
        try
        {
            if (CaminhoPg.Length == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (String Directorio in Directory.GetDirectories(DirName))
                    {
                        System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission ReadPermission =
                            new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, Directorio);

                        var Permisos = new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.None);
                        Permisos.AddPermission(ReadPermission);
                        Boolean Conceder = Permisos.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet);

                        if (Conceder)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                foreach (String dfile in Directory.GetFiles(Directorio, NomeArchivo))
                                {
                                    CaminhoPg = Directorio + "\\";
                                    if (CaminhoPg.Length > 0)
                                    {
                                        Install_Localizado = CaminhoPg;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (CaminhoPg.Length == 0)
                                    RealizarBusca(Directorio, NomeArchivo);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            { Console.WriteLine("Não há permissão para continuar", ex.Message.ToString()); }
                        }
                        else { MessageBox.Show("Não há permissão para seguir em frente"); }
                        if (CaminhoPg != string.Empty)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { Console.WriteLine("Não há permissão para seguir em frente", ex.Message.ToString()); }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Console.WriteLine("Não há permissão para seguir em frente", ex.Message.ToString()); }
        return CaminhoPg;
    }
```

Comment: curiosidade: como foi o desempenho desse código ?

Comment: A primeira vez que ele é executado ele demora um pouco, mas na segunda vez em diante é rápido ... esse código vai ser adaptado e melhorar, mas por enquanto supri a necessidade.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `Directory.GetFiles()` combinado a um `SearchOption` para fazer isso, veja como ficaria:

```
string[] arquivos = { };
string[] filtros = { "pg_dum.exe", "pg_restore.exe" };
foreach (string filtro in filtros)
{
    arquivos = arquivos.Concat(Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), filtro, SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray();
}
```

No meu exemplo coloquei para procurar no `C:\ProgramFiles`, mas em minha opinião isso é um pouco inviável, escolha um lugar mais especifico.

Comment: Certo, mas como funciona, no meu array de arquivos em cada posição eu vou ter o caminho até chegar no pg_dump e pg_restore? 
por exemplo no array arquivos posição [0] eu teria C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\pg_dump.exe

Comment: Editei minha resposta, da uma olhada. @BrunoSilva

Comment: Mas, onde você informa o local a ser procurado? porque em momento algum eu consigo visualizar o `C:\ProgramFiles` no seu código, tipo, procurar todos os filtros pg_dump.exe em `C:\ProgramFiles` mas onde definiu isso?

Comment: Nesse trecho de código: `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` @BrunoSilva

Comment: Acabei de executar sua função, e ela não me retorno o local dos arquivos no filtro :?

Comment: Os arquivos estão dentro dessa pasta `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\` e mesmo assim não foi encontrado

Comment: Apenas funciona quando eu coloco   
`string Diretorio = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\";
 string[] Arquivos = { };
 Arquivos = Directory.GetFiles(Diretorio,"pg_dump.exe");`
Mas ai fica muito enviável pois eu preciso colocar todo o caminho do arquivo kkkkk

Comment: @BrunoSilva Estranho, não sei muito bem qual o problema.

Comment: Vou tentar dar uma pesquisada melhor, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Se você puder executar o programa, elevando o usuário (executar como administrador) você pode simplesmente pegar o processo do postgres que está rodando e olhar o caminho dele:

```
        Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("postgres"); 
        foreach (Process p in ps)
        {
            FileInfo app = new FileInfo(p.MainModule.FileName);
            string dir = app.Directory.FullName;
        }
```

Óbvio que você não precisa do loop, basta pegar apenas um. 
O Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tendo a pasta `bin`, você consegue acesso aos outros binários do postgresql.

Sobre a elevação do usuário, você pode colocar isso junto da aplicação, e quando ela for executada, já solicitar a elevação.

Comment: Entendi, minha duvida é a seguinte, caso eu execute esse código em um outro computador, que no caso não teria o banco de dados pg e faria acesso remoto ao meu sistema ... o vetor ps ficaria em 0?

Comment: Quando eu executo essa função, já com o nivel de administrador ativo ele me retorna o seguinte erro `Um processo de 32 bits não pode acessar módulos de um processo de 64 bits.`

Comment: se não tiver o postgresql no computador, ou seja, é um cliente, sim, o vetor será retornado vazio. Sobre a arquitetura, é possível que seu programa esteja compilando pra 32 bits, e esteja usando o postgresql 64, ou ao contrário. Verifique nas propriedades do seu projeto, build